# what could cause this error in SQL? i am trying to use copy command in SQL and this errors are showing, and i don't know how to do it, the file is CSV

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv

i am trying to use copy command in SQL and this error is showing

> ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp2_sql_resource.zip\data1\students.csv" for reading: Permission denied
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
> SQL state: 42501

see my code below

```
DROP TABLE if exists studentlist;

CREATE TABLE studentlist(
    studentid SERIAL NOT NULL,
    stname VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(150),
    birth DATE,
    entrydate DATE,
    gender VARCHAR(10),
    classnum INT);

COPY studentlist(stname,email,birth,entrydate,gender,classnum )
    FROM 'C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp2_sql_resource.zip\data1\students.csv'DELIMITER','CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: The error is because the Posgtres server cannot read that file inside its `c:\users\HI\AppData\...` folder. Maybe the server does not have permission to read inside that folder. Also, this file you try to load is _inside_ a zip file. This is also a red flag to me. Can you uncompress this into another folder?

Comment: The highest-voted answer in the linked question has detailed steps to resolve this error.